How can I scroll my recyclerView calendar unlimited number of times inside viewpager2
BACKGROUND
I have a calendar project where I created a calendar using a recyclerView, and moving from current month  to next month or current month to previous month I use buttons and all is well and working as expected.
QUESTION
Now I trying to implement a viewpager2 to scroll between months using the same recyclerView. Example: next, previous and current. I have a code below which is able to do that. What I did is I created 1000 itemCounts (or fragments) and when the app is starting it immediately start from fragment number 500 so the calendar will be able to scroll from left and right.
Here is my MainActivity class:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int MAX_COUNT = 1000;
    int TODAY_COUNT = 500;
    String DATE_PATTERN = "MM dd yyyy";
    int prevPosition = 0;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        calendarViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStateAdapter(this) {
            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return MAX_COUNT;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
                return CalendarFragment.newInstance(positionToDateString(position));
            }
        });

        calendarViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                monthText.setText(positionToDateString(position));
                prevPosition = position;
            }
        });

        calendarViewPager.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
        //
        calendarViewPager.setCurrentItem(TODAY_COUNT, false);
    }
    
    public String positionToDateString(int position) {
        
        if (position < prevPosition) {
           calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
         }
        else if (position > prevPosition) {
           calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
         }

        SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN, Locale.ENGLISH);
        String dateString = formatDate.format(calendar.getTime());

        return dateString;
    }
}
}

Please see my fragment class below
I also have a dateManager class which is the one that insert days of each month in a recyclerView.
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    Date date = null;
    String ARG_DATE = "date";
    String DATE_PATTERN = "MM dd yyyy";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN, Locale.JAPAN);
            String dateText = getArguments().getString(ARG_DATE, "");
            try {
                date = format.parse(dateText);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (date != null) {
            DateAdapter adapter = new DateAdapter(requireContext(), date);

            calendarRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), DateManager.DAYS_OF_WEEK, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            calendarRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
    }

    public static CalendarFragment newInstance(String dateString) {
        CalendarFragment fragment = new CalendarFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_DATE, dateString);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}

The program is working fine but I want to be able to scroll the calendar fragments unlimited number of times.
I tried Overriding the onPageScrollStateChanged method.
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged (int state) {
    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        int curr = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        int lastReal = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 2;
        if (curr == 0) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(lastReal, false);
        } else if (curr > lastReal) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
        }
    }
}

But the problem is when I go from fragment 1 to 0, fragment 0 is updated with previous month data and then immediately it goes back to fragment 1 as expected but with current month data, likewise from fragment 1 to fragment 2, 2 is updated with next month data and immediately go back to fragment 1 which has current month data. I also tried some more or less similar techniques without success.
How can I scroll the calendar unlimited number of times and the calendar update as expected.
I want my calendar to scroll like the Google calendar. Maybe Google is not using a recyclerView but I think the concept is the same.
